# thumbnail-header-btn don't appear unless I put the css directly in the browser

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to style the thumbnail header btn, but it doesn't appear in the browser! When I check the element directly in the browser, the css code don't appear and when I put the css code directly in the browser its work. What is the problem?
Here are my html

```
<div class="portfolio">
  <div class="jumbotron"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <row>
        <a class="col-md-6 project", target="_blank">
            <div class="thumbnail-header">
                <div class="thumbnail-header-btn"></div>
                <div class="thumbnail-header-btn"></div>
                <div class="thumbnail-header-btn"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <%= image_tag 'edoss1.png'%>
            </div>
            <h3>Hello</h3>
            <p>This project is ....</p>
        </a>
        <a class="col-md-6 project" href="#">
            <div class="thumbnail-header">
                <div class="thumbnail-header-btn"></div>
                <div class="thumbnail-header-btn"></div>
                <div class="thumbnail-header-btn"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <%= image_tag 'hipme1.png' %>
            </div>
            <h3>Hello</h3>
            <p>This project is ....</p>
        </a>
    </row>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my css

```
.portfolio {
  .container {
    padding: 0 100px;
  }
  .jumbotron {
    background: url("window.png") center center;
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
  }
  .thumbnail {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 1px;
    max-height: 240px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .thumbnail-header {
    background-color: #eaeff4;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
  }
  .thumbnail-header-btn {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 100%;
    float: left;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    width: 10px;
  }
}
```

I'm working on ruby on rails recently. Thanks in advance

Comment: do ```any``` of your styles come through to the browser from this file?

Comment: and that's ```scss``` not ```css```. do you have the 'sass-rails' gem installed?

Comment: In fact, I'm new in coding and it's scss not css. You are right. Yes, the sheet is connected and I can see the .thumbnail-header code and all the other element in the browser but not the .thumbnail-header-btn. It's drive me crazy.

Comment: was that the issue? if so I'll write an answer to this question ...